# XSD Problems with Extension over multiple level

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm trying to generate an XSD to validate an XML with an unknown depth. This is done via an XSLT from an XML. The XML is kinda structured like a class description and every node contains information about the attributes and childs. The XSD has to check another XML which contains the instances. So the XSD has to check if an instance has all the attributes from it's class and it's ancestors.

That's why i tried to solve my problem with types which extend each other.

XML Test File:

```
<!-- language:xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CAEXFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          FileName="Visu_Ruehrreaktor.aml"
          SchemaVersion="2.15"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Validation.xsd">
   <HMI>
      <HMIGraphic Name="Visu_Ruehrreaktor"
                  RefBaseSystemUnitPath="HMISUCLib/Graphic"
                  ID="dce863ca-795b-4d54-9a4c-789b0204f243">
         <h>1080</h>
         <w>1920</w>
         <HMIVisuObjectTextBoxTermination Name="Text01"
                                          RefBaseSystemUnitPath="HMISUCLib/VisuObject/TextBox/Termination"
                                          ID="c0215848-b8b6-4f76-aa2c-3996a053f3fc">
            <text/>
            <tagname>Text01</tagname>
            <x>178</x>
            <y>152</y>
            <h>37</h>
            <w>139</w>
            <role/>
            <type>0001</type>
            <rotation>01</rotation>
            <com_id/>
         </HMIVisuObjectTextBoxTermination>
      </HMIGraphic>
   </HMI>
</CAEXFile>
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
   <xs:complexType name="HMI_type">
      <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
         <xs:element name="HMIGraphic" type="HMIGraphic_type" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:choice>
   </xs:complexType>

   <xs:complexType name="HMIVisuObject_type">
      <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
         <xs:element name="tagname" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="x" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="y" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="h" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="w" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="role" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="rotation" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:choice>
      <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="RefBaseSystemUnitPath" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
   </xs:complexType>

   <xs:complexType name="HMIVisuObjectTextBox_type">
      <xs:complexContent>
         <xs:extension base="HMIVisuObject_type">
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
               <xs:element name="text" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:choice>
         </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="HMIVisuObjectTextBoxTermination_type">
      <xs:complexContent>
         <xs:extension base="HMIVisuObjectTextBox_type">
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            </xs:choice>
         </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="HMIGraphic_type">
      <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
         <xs:element name="HMIVisuObject" type="HMIVisuObject_type" minOccurs="0"/>
         <xs:element name="HMIVisuObjectTextBox"
                     type="HMIVisuObjectTextBox_type"
                     minOccurs="0"/>
         <xs:element name="HMIVisuObjectTextBoxTermination"
                     type="HMIVisuObjectTextBoxTermination_type"
                     minOccurs="0"/>
         <xs:element name="h" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="w" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:choice>
      <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="RefBaseSystemUnitPath" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
   </xs:complexType>

   <xs:element name="CAEXFile">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="HMI" type="HMI_type" minOccurs="0"/>
         </xs:all>
         <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip"/>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The problem is, when ever I run the validation and find an element of type *HMIVisuObjectTextBoxTermination_type* I get an error saying that *text* is not allowed as an element.

> Output/To_Check.aml:15: element text: Schemas validity error : Element 'text': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( tagname, x, y, h, w, role, type, rotation ).

So basically only the elements of the root element of this chain of types. What am I doing wrong and how could I solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Added both files. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your complex type `HMIVisuObjectTextBoxTermination_type` probably has an effective content model which is not what you are expecting.  In XSD 1.0, extension of a complex type creates a sequence containing, first, the content model of the base type and then the material added by the extension.  (Some people find it helpful to think of this as analogous to the addition of new fields at the end of a structure, in extensions to base classes in OO languages.)  Since you have an extension of an extension, what you have is, in effect:

```
 <xs:sequence>
   <!--* complex type HMIVisuObjectTextBox_type *-->
   <xs:sequence>
     <!--* complex type HMIVisuObject_type *-->
     <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <xs:element name="tagname" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="x" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="y" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="h" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="w" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="role" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="rotation" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
     </xs:choice>
     <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <xs:element name="text" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
     </xs:choice>
   </xs:sequence>
   <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
   </xs:choice>
 </xs:sequence>
```

Valid instances must contain sequences of elements which are the concatenation of three subsequences, which match:

- first one or more of tagname, x, y, h, w, role, type, or rotation, followed by
- one or more of text, followed by
- one or more of the empty set.

You have two problems here:  First, judging by your XML, you expected `text` to be added to the set of possible children in the repeatable choice, not to be required to come after all the others.  Second, a choice in a content model is satisfied when the next input item matches one of its children; an empty choice has no children, so nothing can possibly match any of them.  If the choice is required, as the third choice in this sequence it, the choice is unsatisfiable.  That means here that its containing sequence is unsatisfiable, which in turn means that its containing sequence is unsatisfiable, which in turn means that type `HMIVisuObjectTextBoxTermination_type` has no valid instances.  Giving the choice `minOccurs="0"` will allow the type to have valid instances, though they won't be allowed to have the `text` element come first.

**[Addendum]** OP asks " So is there another way than to try to make my XSLT recursive in a way that I copy all of the parents attributes and create a new type ...? What I basically want to do is actually add text to the list of choices, because they all need to be present in xml but they could be in any order."

Several possible approaches offer themselves:

- Specify a fixed sequence for the children.  If the sequence of children is fixed, the type derivation problem becomes trivial.

  So I'd examine very carefully the premise that the order of children must be unconstrained; this is claimed much more frequently than it's true.  It's true if the sequence of children carries information (as it typically does in natural-language documents); it's suspect if the sequence does not carry information.
- Define named model groups for the choices now in HMIVisuObject_type, HMIVisuObjectTextBox_type, etc.  Define the various types in question as choices among the appropriate named model groups.

  ```
  <xs:group name="A">
    <xs:element ref="tagname"/>
    <xs:element ref="x"/>
    <xs:element ref="y"/>
    ...
  </
  <xs:group name="B">
    <xs:element ref="text"/>
    ...
  </
  <xs:group name="C">
    ...
  </

  <xs:complexType name="HMIVisuObject_type">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="A"/>
    ...
  </
  <xs:complexType name="HMIVisuObjectTextBox_type">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:choice ref="A"/>
      <xs:choice ref="B"/>
    </
    ...
  </
  <xs:complexType name="HMIVisuObjectTextBoxTermination_type">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:choice ref="A"/>
      <xs:choice ref="B"/>
      <xs:choice ref="C"/>
    </
    ...
  </
  ```

  This exhibits the relation among the three types clearly to a human reader, and avoids multiple specifications of the same thing.  It does not exhibit the relationship by means of the base-type / derived-type relation between types, and in some environments that will make it less helpful.  (But if you were depending on a mapping to an OO class system, you wouldn't be using repeatable choices in the first place.  So that probably doesn't matter to you, though it will matter to some users.)
- Invert the type hierarchy:  define your most inclusive type as a type and the others as restrictions of it.

  This exhibits the relationship among the types using base/derived links, but the directed links may not be in the direction you would prefer.
- If you are using XSD 1.1, replace the choices in these types with all-groups; in XSD 1.1, a base type with an all-group which is extended by an all-group produces a larger all-group.

Comment: That sounds not so good but thanks so far!
Okay the empty set could be fixed in my XSLT. But that does not fix my problem with the sequence.

So is there another way than to try to make my XSLT recursive in a way that I copy all of the parents attributes and create a new type and forget about solutions?

What I basically want to do is actually add text to the list of choices, because they all need to be present in xml but they could be in any order.